# how to prove that the limit of this sequence of functions is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, normed-spaces

I have a norm that works in function space and that is $‖∙‖_{sup}:C([0,1])→R$, $‖∙‖_{sup}:=sup${$|f(t)|$}. I need to show that the metric is complete.
So I need to show that every Cauchy sequence of functions ($f_{n}$) is convergent. I showed that every ($f_{n}(x_{0}))$ is convergent to $f(x_{0})$ and that ($f_{n}$) is convergent to $f$. But how do i show that $f$ is continuous so that it belongs to C[0,1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is $f$? You need to define it.

Of course, you'll define $f$ to be the pointwise limit of the $f_n$.

To proceed, first show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$. Towards this end, keep in mind that $(f_n)$ is a uniformly Cauchy sequence and that for any $x$
$$
|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} |f_m(x)-f_n(x)|.
$$

(It seems you may have already done all this, but it's hard to tell from your post.)

Now you're set to show  $f$ is indeed continuous. To do that, argue as in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) (or, perhaps, you could simply appeal to the result there).

Answer (score 1):

This does not follow from pointwise convergence.  What you actually showed is that $f_n$ converges to $f$ *uniformly*, because your estimate is independent of the point $x_0$. By Cauchy's celebrated theorem a uniform limit is necessarily continuous. Presumably the point of the exercise was to test your understanding of the material on uniform convergence.